# How to search XML file for specific elements without loading all elements?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to load the drawable names from appfilter.xml related to one of the installed icon packs, as you know that such file could contain 1000s of elements (sometimes more than 8000).

I found this code online which do the job but it loads all elements into the array, and for a better memory management and to avoid memory churn, I want to only search this file for the elements that I need (which could be a couple of 100s) and add them into my array.

So how could I accomplish this? What do you advise me

Code:

https://github.com/michelelacorte/FlickLauncher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher3/util/IconPackManager.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take their code.  Create a HashSet of all the names you want.  In the section where they add it to the array, add a check to see if the name is contained in your set.  If it is, add it.  If not, skip.  Its a really simple alteration.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, Say I have a 100 app, what you say is, as I go through the 8000 elements, I check every element against my HashSet (That has 100 app or so), is this a memory and cpu friendly process?

Comment: And another thing, if a new app got installed, do I go through the same process of looping through the 8000 elements until I find the desired element? I'm torn between CPU friendly process and RAM friendly process. Knowing that in general usage there will be no new app installed every minute.

Comment: Its a CPU friendly process.  A HashSet is O(1) insertion and search.  Memory-  pretty much.  While the set exists, it would take up a some memory (hash sets aren't the most memory efficient structure) but it could be cleared up when you're done, and would only have a few hundred entries.  And its much more friendly than loading everything.

Comment: Again thank you for your help and for assuring me, really appreciated.